# hadoop mapreduce: handling a text file with a header

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I'm playing & learning hadoop MapReduce.

I'm trying to map data from a **VCF** file ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format ) : a VCF is a tab-delimited file starting with a (possibly large) header. This header is required to get the semantics of the records in the body.

[image: http://wiki.bits.vib.be/index.php/NGS_Exercise.5]

I'd like to create a Mapper that would use those data. The header must be accessible from this Mapper in order to decode the lines.

From http://jayunit100.blogspot.fr/2013/07/hadoop-processing-headers-in-mappers.html  , I've created this **InputFormat**, with a custom Reader :

```
  public static class VcfInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text>
    {
    /* the VCF header is stored here */
    private List<String> headerLines=new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
            TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        return new VcfRecordReader();
        }  
    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
        return false;
        }

     private class VcfRecordReader extends LineRecordReader
        {
        /* reads all lines starting with '#' */
         @Override
        public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit,
                TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException {
            super.initialize(genericSplit, context);
            List<String> headerLines=new ArrayList<String>();
            while( super.nextKeyValue())
                {
                String row = super.getCurrentValue().toString();
                if(!row.startsWith("#")) throw new IOException("Bad VCF header");
                headerLines.add(row);
                if(row.startsWith("#CHROM")) break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, in the **Mapper**, is there a way to have a pointer to the `VcfInputFormat.this.headerLines` in order to decode the lines ?

```
  public static class VcfMapper
       extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      my.VcfCodec codec=new my.VcfCodec(???????.headerLines);
      my.Variant variant =codec.decode(value.toString());
      //(....)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your case is different from the example you linked to. In that case, the header is used inside the custom `RecordReader` class in order to provide a single "current value" which is a line composed by all the filtered words, and which is passed to the mapper. However, in your case you want to use the headers information outside the `RecordReader`, i.e. at you mapper, and that cannot be achieved.

I also think you can mimic the linked example behaviour by providing already processed information as well: by reading the headers, storing them and then, when getting the current value, your mapper can receive a `my.VcfCodec` object instead of a `Text` object (i.e. the `getCurrentValue` method returns a `my.VcfCodec` object). Your mapper could be something like...

```
public static class VcfMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, my.VcfCodec, Text, IntWritable>{
    public void map(LongWritable key, my.VcfCodec value, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // whatever you may want to do with the encoded data...
}
```

Comment: do you mean that each row from my file would embed the whole header ?

Comment: No, I mean each time a line is going to be passed to your mapper, it is previously encoded at the `RecordReader` as a `my.VcfCodec` object; this means no `Text` object is really passed to the Mapper but a `my.VcfCodec` object instead. This way, there is no need to access nor pass the headers to the mapper, becasue the information arrives already encoded to the mapper.

Comment: I edited because the `value` parameter at the `map` method was of a wrong type. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your input format class is fine, as @frb said inputformat class will not be able to give differentiation between the meta data and the records.

One idea that I can suggest is ,

- Declare static global variables in the mapper class for every meta
  data property of the VCF file such as fileformat, date, source etc..
- From the VcfInputFormat class read through lines , if the line start
  with `'##'` then parse the line and set the value to the static
  variable of the mapper class accordin to the property name in the
  current line.
- if the line doesn't start with `'##'` then simply pass the line to the
  mapper
- In mapper class, just parse the record contents and derive useful
  values with the help of static variables represents the meta data.

hope this helps..